How to write a newcommand with \hrulefill which I can control like \fillwithdottedlines{} in exam class
I am currently using book class to prepare learner's write in workbook as in MWE below:
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\newcommand*\myblank{\\[2ex]\hrulefill\\[2ex]\hrulefill\\[2ex]\hrulefill\\[2ex]}
\begin{document}
Let me use this newcommand 
\myblank
It produces three lines but I would like to produce any number of lines by simply typing \myblank{2}, \myblank{6} to produce 2 lines, 6 lines etc like those in exam class.
\end{document}

Thanks in advance

are you trying to create a blank space, solid lines or dotted lines? because your code produces blank space, but your title  suggests you want dots and your text suggests 'lines', which could mean many things.

@cfr I would like to create solid lines

I use fillwith for this kind of thing, but it is more designed around filling a certain space than producing a certain number of lines. possibly could be modified ....

It's not clear whether you want empty lines, solid lines or dotted lines. Assuming you just want to skip some lines to leave the space empty, you could use something like this, which defines \myblank[<number>] to add <number> times the current \baselineskip, where [<number>] is optional and defaults to 2.
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\newcommand*\myblank[1][2]{%
  \par\noindent\vspace*{\dimexpr #1\baselineskip}\par\noindent
  % \\[2ex]\hrulefill\\[2ex]\hrulefill\\[2ex]\hrulefill\\[2ex]%
}
\begin{document}
Let me use this newcommand
\myblank
It produces three lines but I would like to produce any number of lines by simply typing \myblank[2], \myblank[6] to produce 2 lines, 6 lines etc like those in exam class.
\end{document}

